How to get Ngenius Order Reference located in Magento 2 Ngenius Reports Using REST API or Custom Module?
We are using Ngenius Online Payment for our Magento 2.3.5 and after placing orders via Ngenius, we can see the order reference id and payment id in Ngenius Reports in Reports -> Sales -> Ngenius Report section in admin panel:

I need to create a REST API or custom module so by providing the order id, I can get the Order Reference.
But since it's a custom module, the order reference is not in the rest/v1/orders/{orderid}
Any idea how to retrieve the order reference in ngenius report section?
Thanks
